# java.lang.NullPointerException al pasar un objeto por parámetro

Tags: java, netbeans

espero anden bien.
Estoy teniendo problemas con un programa MVC el cual intenta pasar por parametro desde la vista al controlador dos objetos y desde el controlador al Modelo ( el cual arroja error de puntero Null ).

Los mismos son bien pasados ( en modo debug puedo ver los valores en el controlador ), donde es recibido por su correspondiente constructor y mueve la referencia de esos objetos a las variables de clase del mismo controlador.

Acto seguido, paso los valores ingresados en los textbox del formulario a la instancia de la variable de clase ( tipo Empleado ) y ese objeto es pasado como parametro a otra clase de la capa Modelo para continuar los controles.

El problema radica en que cuando el controlador quiere ejecutar el metodo de la clase Modelo, el objeto pasado como parametro arroja un error de puntero NULL.

Este ejercicio lo estoy haciendo (siguiendo un video de youtube el cual funciona ) y no encuentro la falla o mi posible error. les comparto el codigo a continuacion:

Clase inicio (instancio el formulario de login y paso los datos ingresados al controlador ):
package mvc;

```
import vista.*;
import controlador.*;
import templates.*;

public class InicioMVC {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        //instancio los objetos de cada clase
        tpltUsuarios users =new tpltUsuarios();
        frmLogin frm =new frmLogin();

        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setVisible(true);
        ctrlLogin  ctrl =new ctrlLogin(users, frm);

    }    
}
```

---

Clase Controlador ( cargo los datos pasados desde la instancia de inicio )

```
package controlador;

import modelo.mdlValidoUsuario;
import vista.frmLogin;
import templates.tpltUsuarios;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ctrlLogin implements ActionListener {

    private tpltUsuarios user;
    private frmLogin frm;
    private mdlValidoUsuario valUser;


    //Armo un constructor de la clase para pasar por parametros los objetos
    public ctrlLogin(tpltUsuarios user, frmLogin frm){    
        this.user = user;
        this.frm  = frm;
        //declaro las acciones de los botos del formulario
        this.frm.btnLogin.addActionListener(this);//pongo a la escucha el boton 
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        user.setUserRed(frm.txtUserRed.getText());
        user.setPassword(frm.txtPassword.getText());

        try {
            if ( valUser.validarEmpleado(user) ){      <----ACA DA EL ERROR !!!!!
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuario validado OK");
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuario ERROR");
            }introducir el código aquí`

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            //Logger.getLogger(ctrlLogin.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.err.println(e);
        }


    }
}
```

---

un fragmento de la salida:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controlador.ctrlLogin.actionPerformed(ctrlLogin.java:34)

Desde ya les agradezco el tiempo 
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Perdon, ya encontré el problema.  Desde el inicio del main() me falto instanciar la clase modelo donde se encuentra el metodo al cual invoco en el controlador.
de esta manera , al solo usarlo desde el controlador, la variable de clase no apuntaba a nunguna direccion de memoria por eso quedaba con el puntero NULL.

Saludos